# startActivity crashes when trying to respond to menu click

Tags: android

I know this has been covered elsewhere, but I'm new to the Android platform and am having a hard time figuring out how to add basic menu options to my first app.

I have an options menu setup using

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
  return true;
}
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/menuPrefs" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences" android:title="Settings"></item>
</menu>
```

Then within my main java class I have

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

 if(item.getItemId()==R.id.menuPrefs) {
  showPrefs();
 }
private void showPrefs() {
 Intent i = new Intent(this, Prefs.class);
 startActivity(i);
}
```

And then in Prefs.java I have

```
public class Prefs extends Activity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "FNORD", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
    }
```

Now from this I would expect to see the Toast message "FNORD" when the menu option is pressed, however the application stops unexpectedly.

If I move the toast statement into the showPrefs() function in place of the startActivity call it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn how to Debug in Eclipse and how to use the [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) and [DDMS](https://web.archive.org/web/20120618172953/http://developer.android.com:80/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html) tools.

In order to get more details about an exception/force close you need to look for a view in Eclipse called [Logcat](https://web.archive.org/web/20100324231958/http://developer.android.com:80/intl/de/guide/developing/debug-tasks.html)(you will find in the [DDMS](https://web.archive.org/web/20170825232742/http://www.brighthub.com:80/mobile/google-android/articles/25023.aspx) perspective) there you will find a detailed traceback when/what and on what line is the issue.

For this you should read a complete article about [Debugging in Android using Eclipse](http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html)

[image]
<sub>(source: [droidnova.com](http://www.droidnova.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/debugging-3.gif))</sub>

Comment: The link you provided fails to open, however I did manage to find the source of the problem. "android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class", so I need to declare the activity in AndroidManifest.xml. Forgive my ignorance, but how does one go about doing that? Having a hard time finding a good example.

Comment: Never mind, simply added <activity android:name="Prefs"></activity> to the manifest and that seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call `super.onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);` on Prefs' `onCreate()` method.

Comment: When I read this I asked myself: where?. So I added to your answer.

Comment: I assume you mean "super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);". Adding it has no effect on the crash. I removed it and all code other then the Toast call in the Prefs.java onCreate function to try and eliminate potential causes, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was that I needed to add the Prefs.xml to the manifest.